# Unable to convert raster to polyline

Tags: raster, arcgis-pro, polyline-creation, reclassify, extract-by-mask

I'm having trouble successfully converting a raster to a polyline feature in ArcGIS Pro. My ultimate goal is to take the values from a raster image and join them to a line layer so that I can symbolize the lines based on the values from the raster.

My thought process for this analysis was to:

1. Extract by mask using the line feature as a mask.
2. Reclassify the extracted raster.
3. Use the thin tool to make the raster appear more like a line feature.
4. Use the raster to polyline tool.
5. Spatial join the new polyline feature to the original line layer.

The problem I am running into occurs when trying to use the thin tool. It still looks rather pixelated and not similar to the original line feature it was extracted from. Also, it seems to have removed my classifications that I made in the previous step. This is what I'm getting:

[image]

Here is the original line layer:

[image]

Here is the original raster layer:

[image]

Am I using the wrong tools for this analysis?

Is my raster too pixelated for this type of analysis?

Or maybe I'm not using the right resolution for one of the geoprocessing steps?

Comment: Sorry, I should have clarified that in my post. I'm using ArcGIS Pro v3.2

Comment: More details about the extent of the vector and the parameters used in the vectorization process are necessary. The easiest way to capture parameters is to go to the geoprocessing history and "Copy as Python".

Comment: As per the [Tour] there should be only one question asked per question.